# What about CoreMIDI framework support in MonoTouch?

Tags: xamarin.ios, coremidi

according to the Mono Documentation Library it seems that MonoTouch currently (3.2.5) doesn't support CoreMIDI framework (available in iOS 4.2, the version I'm working on).

Will CoreMIDI be supported in MonoTouch 4.0?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It doesn't seem to be available yet. This is where I look to find bindings to Objective C libraries: https://github.com/mono/monotouch-bindings

The Mono guys are adding stuff there from time to time, last one was CorePlot, added about a week ago.